# Форма обратной связи

Tags: html, php

Вот делаю небольшой сайт, где должна быть форма обратной связи. Заказчик еще не определился, будет ли хостинг поддерживать php-скрипты. Так вот, возможно ли такую форму создать только средствами html?

Comment: [Используйте подобные решения](http://masterform.info/)

Comment: >Заказчик еще не определился, будет ли хостинг поддерживать php-скрипты.

А может не выделываться и объяснить начальнику, что не "будет ли", а "будет" - и ничего неопределённого?

Comment: это что-то новое, чтобы хостинг не поддерживал PHP)) или сразу за ноде пишем?)

Answer (score 1):

[Отправка писем с помощью javascript](https://habrahabr.ru/post/246347/)

Здесь статья о том, как отправить письмо через javascript.

[Отправка письма на чистом html5(eng)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24026898/how-to-send-an-email-using-only-html5-and-css)

Тут вообще всё просто - чел предлагает использовать "mailto:" - при нажатии отправки запустится программа, которая у пользователя на компьютере выбрана для работы с почтой.

Но лучше и правда одуматься и уговорить на php, ведь php делает людей счастливее.

Answer (score 0):

На одном только html?
Разве что использовать ajax на другой сервер.
Выход № 2 - сторонние сервисы:
[Google Forms](https://habrahabr.ru/post/148332/)